# Loading jsp page using jQuery .load() causes issue with fmt:message

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jsp-tags

I have jsp page that I want to load using .load() function and in page that I want to load there are fmt's, < fmt :message key="some_text"/ >, < select> filters and so on. Everything works "perfectly". Page loads, fmt's load. But the problem is that after I spend 10 minutes or so on that page and and want to use filters, and when page reloads fmt's are not loaded. I get something like this **???some_text???**.

Here is the ajax call

```
$('#some_div').load('/ajax/re/load.jsp', ajaxOptions);
```

And here is the load.jsp file

```
<%@taglib prefix="sw" uri="/WEB-INF/sw.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="menu" tagdir="/WEB-INF/
<div id="js-search-box" class="search-box">
    <label>
        <input id="div_id_${param.itemId}" type="text" placeholder="   <fmt:message key="search"/>">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Did anyone had similar problem? 
Thanks

Comment: show some code.The jquery load() call, the jsp, the filters and the deployment descriptor could be interesting

Comment: It's a simple jquery load cal  $('#some_element').on('change' , function(){
$('#some_div').load('/path_to_file/some_page.jsp');
 }); The code is pretty big so can't separate it.

Comment: you said that filters are involved. The issue could be there. They can change the response. Try to extract and show some of the related code.

Comment: Filters are in my previous comment, and are select list. I added some additional code. And I'm not sure which part of the deployment descriptor I should add?

Comment: Could be issue in rendering a taglib in loaded jsp,can you try using some other taglib such as JSTL or others to check this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I've had the same problem today and this is the only thing that popped up on google and it hasn't been answered.

My problem (and the one in the question) was that i forgot to put encoding for the page.

Put `<%@page pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html"%>` at the top and you'll be fine.

Otherwise, if this wasn't your problem, then your bundles are probably getting mixed up. Set them again at the begging of your page with `<fmt:setBundle ...` and `<fmt:setLocale ...`